# How to create a grid in WebGL with Babylon.js?

Tags: webgl, babylonjs

I am a newbie with babylon.js and webGL. I want to create a grid example 3 x 3 grid and place objects in the cells. Also, I always want to know in which cell the object is present if there is one.

Update :

I want to end up with a cube which has 3 rows 3 columns on each face. I can create a tiled plane for each face but I won't know what are the contents in each cell. Is there any way ?

Can someone guide me doing it ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Are you asking about the visualization of such a grid? 3x3 of what? cubes?

Comment: Check the updated question. Thank you !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So now that it's clearer - Babylon.js is just used to render this 3x3 grid.
The simplest way would be to create a grid item and store 1x1x1 boxes in it. this way it will look like a big cube, but will still consist of smaller items.

I have created a very simple playground demo to get you started - http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#2CFAMI

This, of course, should be optimized and adjusted to your usecase, but this would be a simple way to create a 3x3x3 grid with boxes in different colors.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your work. It may not work as I expected because I am creating a puzzle in the cube. It might come handy at some point. I used blender to create such cube and imported it. Am still working on the puzzle and placing the things in cube etc.. Thanks again !!